# Initialize an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object filled this way:

```
[...]
time: '',
age: '',
items:      {
                shirt: {selected: false, max_price: '250'},
                pants: {selected: false, max_price: '250'},
                dress: {selected: false, max_price: '250'},
                shoe: {selected: false, max_price: '250'}
            },
request: '',
[...]
```

I have to set up a Schema "template" to prepare the push to the database and to tell what type does each variable expect. And this is where I'm lost, I don't know how to fulfil the object using types.

```
 [...]
age:        { type: Number},
items :         {
                        type: String:
                        {selected: type: boolean, max_price: Number} // I have no idea
                    },
request:   { type: String },
 [...]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is this? A homework assignment? If so, is this particular assignment in a book?

Comment: I don't really get your questions. It is for a project, and I'm new to javascript

Comment: Your question is vague, I cannot place it into any context. So it sounds like a homework assignment. If it is, I'd rather read the question verbatim.

Comment: Yeah ahah that's because I'm lost about it, so sorry D:
So I'd like to fulfil the 'items' object (in the second code) using the types shown in the first one (selected which is a boolean, max_price a number)

Comment: I see...expect an answer shortly.

Comment: So I deleted my answer because your question cannot be guessed into a right answer if you yourself do not know enough to properly ask a question, you need to research more into this subject, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
// User class.
function User(userData) {
  this.data = userData;

  return {
    save: function() {
      // Let's use some validation library here (validatorjs, chaijs,..) to validate the input value against schema.
      someValidator(User._schema, this.data);
      ...
    }
    delete: function() {...}
  }
}

// Static (but not private) variable. To make it private, Google Search for OOP in javascript.
User._schema = {
  age:        { type: Number},
  items :         {
                         type: String:
                         {selected: type: boolean, max_price: Number} // I have no idea
                     },
  request:   { type: String },
};

// Use your object.
var newUser = new User({....});
newUser.save();
```